# Case/when, ajuda

Tags: sql, case, when

Dei uma procurada e não consegui achar uma logica pra utilizar nesse caso.

as colunas da tabela são:
**COD_DO_USUARIO_ONE | COD_DO_USUARIO_TWO | TEXTO**

basicamente estou tentando montar um codigo que consiga identificar quem foi o primeiro a enviar uma certa mensagem no chat particular de um fórum ...

pensei no seguinte Código(que está funcionando)

```
case     
    when lower(texto) like '%oi, tudo bem?%' THEN 'user1'
    else 'user2'
    end AS usuario_forum
```

Isso me retorna o COD de quem enviou a mensagem, porém, problema é o seguinte:

1 - o texto pode ter sido disparado tanto pele user_one como pelo user_two, então como foi saber quem foi o primeiro a falar?

exemplo:
user 1 - oi, tudo bem? 
user 2 - tudo

logica 2
user 1 - oi
user 2 - oi, tudo bem?

Como a logica do primeiro cod estava incorreta pense modifiquei e ficou da seguinte forma:

```
case
when lower(texto) like '%oi, tudo bem?%' = COD_DO_USUARIO_ONE THEN 'user1'
else 'user2'
end AS usuario_forum
```

não funciona pois o código do usuário não é igual o texto mencionado, então não consigo igualar os 2

tentei um `IF` no select, porém não deu certo pelo mesmo motivo.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso criar trazer essa coluna com os dados certos?

Comment: Isto que você colocou não tem o menor sentido. O que você quer comparar com COD_DO_USUARIO_ENVIO? Talvez você tenha pensado em encadear dois case/when?

Comment: então, sei que a logica esta errada, não consigo igualar o COD_DO_USUARIO_ONE com o TEXTO ... mas como faço pra saber queme enviou a mensagem ? se foi o user 1 ou o user 2?

Comment: Creio que você só vai conseguir identificar quem primeiro enviou tal texto se sua tabela também incluir um timestamp do envio e supondo que COD_DO_USUARIO_ONE foi quem enviou e COD_DO_USUARIO_TWO foi quem recebeu.

Comment: Não necessariamente, imagina a seguinte texto like "oi, tudo bem" ... agora a seguinte conversa: user_one: oi  user_two: oi, tudo bem? quem enviou foi o two

Comment: Mas a ideia foi boa, no que eu quero deve vim o grosso de tudo, na guerra alguns soldados sempre saem feridos rsrs se tiver alguma outra ideia, ultimo caso vou usar essa que vc disse mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, seria algo assim:

```
DECLARE @TABELA_TEMP TABLE
(
    COD_DO_USUARIO INT
    , TEXTO VARCHAR(MAX)
    , DATA_ENVIO DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @TABELA_TEMP VALUES (1, 'mensagem 1', '2019-02-13 18:12')
INSERT INTO @TABELA_TEMP VALUES (1, 'mensagem 2', '2019-02-13 18:11')
INSERT INTO @TABELA_TEMP VALUES (2, 'mensagem 1', '2019-02-13 18:11')
INSERT INTO @TABELA_TEMP VALUES (2, 'mensagem 2', '2019-02-13 18:16')
INSERT INTO @TABELA_TEMP VALUES (3, 'mensagem 1', '2019-02-13 18:15')
INSERT INTO @TABELA_TEMP VALUES (3, 'mensagem 2', '2019-02-13 18:10')

SELECT TOP 1 MAX(DATA_ENVIO) DATA_ENVIO, COD_DO_USUARIO FROM @TABELA_TEMP WHERE TEXTO = 'mensagem 2' GROUP BY COD_DO_USUARIO ORDER BY DATA_ENVIO DESC
```